# Make new devexpress report from existing report

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress

I have an existing devexpress report. I want to create an identical report just using a different query for the data. Is there a way to copy the existing report and then just change the query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XtraReport is just a class with a designer file, like a Windows Form. You can copy those and rename them, or export the existing report to the repx format and import that into a new XtraReport.

Comment: Thanks, I was just thrown by the devexpress screen throwing errors at me.